# odd recording qtp

Tags: automation, qtp

when i was creating text chepoing in qtp the recording results getting odd recording results

the scanned input is

[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8255/capture1pa.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8255/capture1pa.png)

and i get output like this insted of secs it display sees

[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/5273/capture2c.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/5273/capture2c.png)

and i made change in text like this sees to secs

[alt text http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/7492/capture4f.png](http://img801.imageshack.us/img801/7492/capture4f.png)

but when i run the test the test result will be

[alt text http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2575/capture3z.png](http://img94.imageshack.us/img94/2575/capture3z.png)

I captured many times but it display same as above. I don't understand how display like this, please help me.

Comment: What happens if you replace `secs` in your Checked Text with `sees`?

Comment: What options are specified in Tools > Options > General > Text Recognition?

Comment: @Pourquoi it is checking sees compared with secs and it continuous fails the test case

Comment: Also, is the Checked Text treated as a regular expression, i.e. is the Regular Expression option selected for it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that QTP recognizes the word *secs* in your application as *sees*, which causes the checkpoint to fail. Most probably, this happens because the text recognition is performed using [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition), which can't guarantee 100% accuracy. You can try changing the text recognition mechanism to Windows API and see if that helps. To do this, go to **Tools > Options > General > Text Recognition** and set the **Use text recognition mechanisms in this order** option to either *Use Only Windows API* or *First Windows API then OCR*.

If this doesn't help, you can replace the word *secs* in the checkpoint's Checked Text with a regular expression that matches both *secs* and *sees*:

> [0-9]+ days, [0-9]+ hours, [0-9]+ mins, [0-9]+ **se[ce]s**

Also, make sure that the **Regular Expression** option is turned on for the Checked Text.

Comment: thanks for u r replay, i check that one, it fails, but i create standard checkpoint it works for me.